# Full page reload (Ctrl+F5) maintain scroll position in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, browser, browser-cache

Is it possible to maintain scroll position when making a full page reload (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) in Firefox instead of jumping to the top of the page?

When I make a full page reload in Chrome it maintain the scroll position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up the Network Monitor using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and check the "Disable cache" checkbox, Firefox should maintain scroll position upon refreshing using just the F5 key.

Answer (score 0):

The way proposed by the accepted answer didn't work for me. For me I have to use plugins. There are two plugins I found can do this:

- Scrollmark  (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrollmark/)
- Scrollsave (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrollsave/)